# Audible pause with looping in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation and numberOfLoops = -1  to loop a sound when called. When the sound has finished playing (and loops to the beginning), there is a very slight but noticeable gap between the sounds. I want the transition to be seamless. I have followed a suggestion to use m4a files to no avail.

```
var soundPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
@IBOutlet var buttonPlay: UIButton!
    let soundLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("soundexample", ofType: ".m4a")
    do {
        soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundLocation!))

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
    catch {
        print(error)
    }


}
```

Then the button action:

```
@IBAction func soundButtonTap(sender: UIButton) {
    if (!sender.selected) {
        soundPlayer.play()
        soundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    else {
        soundPlayer.stop()
    }
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

Comment: Check to see if the audio that you're using has any gaps at the beginning or at the end

Comment: Can you post some code? And an example file?

Comment: The audio files have already been edited to ensure a smooth transition and tested in other programs (iTunes and others). I have amended the question to show the code framework that is being used.

Comment: Try using linear PCM (uncompressed) audio, like .wav

Comment: Still no luck - still hearing a gap